# Why onDestroy method of a Service Not Calling when mobile switch off?

Tags: android, android-service, ondestroy

My requirement is send a request to the server with mobile switch on/off status and update the `mongodb` database mobile switch on/off status.
To do this I am using an `Service`. In my `Service` `onCreate` method I added the code to send a request with switch on status and update database. It is working properly. I need to send switch off status when mobile switched off and that code part I added to `Service onDestroy` method. But it is not working , at least  `Service onDestroy` method is not calling when mobile switch off.

Can Anyone give me the solution for that and How to I send a request from `Service` when Mobile switched off ?

Comment: It would really help if you could provide some code snippets to show what you have tried, and where you think the problem is. Also, if you have any log snippets that show where the action is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is not obligated to go through the entire application lifecycle when it is shutting down the system. Just like it does not call `onDestroy` if the application crashes.

One way you can generally work around this is instead of relying on the application to explicitly report being alive/dead, you have it periodically report in. Then you consider the application dead if it does not report in for a certain period.